# order by max value multidimension array/object

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object

I need to order this array/object by max value desc grossConversions
from max to min
max 10 results

I have this output to order

```
    array(19) {
  [0] => object(stdClass) #355 (8) { ["campaign_name"]= > string(27)
  "Scrub Viso Granuli Vegetali" ["campaign_id"] => int(14)["currency"] => string(3)
  "EUR" ["approvedConversions"] => int(0)["pendingConversions"] => int(0)["grossConversions"] => int(0)["payout"] => int(0)["pendingPayout"] => int(0)
} [1] => object(stdClass) #356 (8) { ["campaign_name"]= > string(33)
"Crema Viso/collo Acido Jaluronico" ["campaign_id"] => int(16)["currency"] => string(3)
"EUR" ["approvedConversions"] => int(0)["pendingConversions"] => int(0)["grossConversions"] => int(0)["payout"] => int(0)["pendingPayout"] => int(0)
} [2] => object(stdClass) #357 (8) { ["campaign_name"]= > string(13)
"Home Training" ["campaign_id"] => int(5)["currency"] => string(3)
"EUR" ["approvedConversions"] => int(0)["pendingConversions"] => int(0)["grossConversions"] => int(0)["payout"] => int(0)["pendingPayout"] => int(0)
} [3] => object(stdClass) #358 (8) { ["campaign_name"]= > string(25)
"4x Libri di apprendimento" ["campaign_id"] => int(4)["currency"] => string(3)
"EUR" ["approvedConversions"] => int(1)["pendingConversions"] => int(0)["grossConversions"] => int(2)["payout"] => int(15)["pendingPayout"] => int(0)
} [4] => object(stdClass) #359 (8) { ["campaign_name"]= > string(26)
"Tin-UP - Abbronzante Spray" ["campaign_id"] => int(11)["currency"] => string(3)
"EUR" ["approvedConversions"] => int(0)["pendingConversions"] => int(0)["grossConversions"] => int(0)["payout"] => int(0)["pendingPayout"] => int(0)
} [5] => object(stdClass) #360 (8) { ["campaign_name"]= > string(23)
"Aspirapolvere Ciclonica" ["campaign_id"] => int(22)["currency"] => string(3)
"EUR" ["approvedConversions"] => int(0)["pendingConversions"] => int(0)["grossConversions"] => int(0)["payout"] => int(0)["pendingPayout"] => int(0)
} [6] => object(stdClass) #361 (8) { ["campaign_name"]= > string(15)
"Centurion Power" ["campaign_id"] => int(12)["currency"] => string(3)
"EUR" ["approvedConversions"] => int(0)["pendingConversions"] => int(0)["grossConversions"] => int(0)["payout"] => int(0)["pendingPayout"] => int(0)
} [7] => object(stdClass) #362 (8) { ["campaign_name"]= > string(27)
"Tonico Te' Bianco Te' Rosso" ["campaign_id"] => int(10)["currency"] => string(3)
"EUR" ["approvedConversions"] => int(0)["pendingConversions"] => int(0)["grossConversions"] => int(0)["payout"] => int(0)["pendingPayout"] => int(0)
} [8] => object(stdClass) #363 (8) { ["campaign_name"]= > string(10)
"Air Freeze" ["campaign_id"] => int(13)["currency"] => string(3)
"EUR" ["approvedConversions"] => int(0)["pendingConversions"] => int(1)["grossConversions"] => int(3)["payout"] => int(0)["pendingPayout"] => int(16)
} [9] => object(stdClass) #364 (8) { ["campaign_name"]= > string(17)
"Monopattino Urban" ["campaign_id"] => int(25)["currency"] => string(3)
"EUR" ["approvedConversions"] => int(0)["pendingConversions"] => int(0)["grossConversions"] => int(0)["payout"] => int(0)["pendingPayout"] => int(0)
}
}
```

how Can I order by max value grossConversions DESC?
I have try

```
 function cmp($a, $b) {
                if ($a['grossConversions'] == $b['grossConversions']) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return ($a['grossConversions'] < $b['grossConversions']) ? 1 : -1;
            }

            uasort($getReportCampaign->records, 'cmp');
```

but I get this error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your lines of your array are standard object. I guess you have done **json_decode**

So instead of this

```
$a['grossConversions']
```

do that

```
$a->grossConversions
```

Or if you want to use array, do

```
json_decode(json_encode($my_array, true), true)
```

it will "convert" your stdClass as an associative array thanks to the **true** param of **json_decode** (cf [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php))